# Show that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are independent $σ$-fields.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Ω = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}, F = 2^Ω$,
$P(\{1\}) = P(\{4\}) = P(\{5\}) = 1/6$,
$P(\{2\}) = P(\{3\}) = 1/12$ and $P(\{6\}) = 1/3$. Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ denote the
$σ$-fields on $Ω$ generated, respectively, by $(\{1, 2\}, \{3, 5\})$ and $\{2, 3, 4\}$.
Show that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are independent $σ$-fields.

Try : I got $F_1 = \{ \Phi , \{1,2\} , \{3,5\} , \{3,4,5,6\} , \{1,2,4,6\}, Ω \}$.
$F_2 = \{Φ , \{2,3,4\} \{1,5,6\} , Ω\}$
How will you prove them to be independent? The definition says EVERY $A$ belonging to $F_1$ IS independent of every $B$ belonging to $F_2$.

Comment: Use `$\Phi,\Omega,\{1,2,3\}$` to show $\Phi,\Omega,\{1,2,3\}$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Show that $\mathbb P(AB)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)$ for each $A\in\mathcal F_1$, $B\in\mathcal F_2$.